# How can I ensure a css-generated svg file doesn't take up more space than the actual image? Visibly, my wave is 239px height but svg is 1500px

Tags: css, svg

I used an online tool to create svg css here: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

When I use it on my page it renders as it should (height and width wise) but when I inspect the page the svg file is 1512px by 1512px, which is 1200px+ too large. How can I make sure it only takes up the space it should?

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    z-index:-1;
}
.wave-container {
    padding-top:50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wave-container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M 0 0 H 563 V 32 C 222 114 168 -4 1 1" style="stroke: none; fill:#003349;"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I tried to render the svg using css to create a wave background. It works visually but takes up too much invisible space as a .svg.

I tried setting a max height of say 500px but it ruins the svg file and crops it to about 10% width and height.

On the online tool I had it as "Absolute" values if that makes any difference.

Comment: Your SVG has `preserveAspectRatio="none"`. Do you expect the SVG to be a square? So stretching the height of the wave. And then it is not clear to me how wide should the SVG be in pixel?

Comment: I would use a different viewBox attribute. Please try `viewBox="0 0 563 62"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your SVG looks like now, relative to its viewbox (the white square):

[image]

This is what it looks like with the viewbox adjusted as follows:

```
viewBox="0 0 563 62"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i needed!